# How I can convert a point layer to a polygon layer in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, polygon, point, buffer

I need each point with its diameter to be a polygon
[image: these are the points]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you have a column in the attribute table that stores the diameter values, you can use that column to feed the buffer tool as follows:

1. Select the input point layer.
2. From the `Data Defined Override` select the column that stores the Diameter values.
3. Segments write 50 to have smooth round segments.
4. Save the file to a disk.
5. Run the tool.

[image]

Here is the output:

[image]